Is there any way to change the Python version linked to QGIS?
I am developing a plugin for QGIS and as a requirement the user must install a Python package called wntr (https://github.com/USEPA/WNTR). I am doing some tests on other computers to check for errors in the plugin and I installed the QGIS 3.34 LTR version. During the test on a computer with Windows 11 operating system, an error occurred when installing the wntr package, because Python 3.12 was installed with QGIS, which generates errors when installing some packages, including wntr. The alternative I found to solve the problem was to downgrade Python to a version lower than 3.12. That said, my question is whether there is a way to change the version of Python linked to QGIS and whether before installing QGIS it is possible to choose which version of Python to use?
Just to specify the problem that occurred during the installation of wntr: to install this package you need to have a C++ compiler on your computer, I installed the Microsoft C++ Build Tools (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). On another computer whose QGIS version is 3.28 and Python is 3.9 it was possible to install WNTR only by installing this C++ compiler, however, using QGIS 3.34 and Python 3.12 the following error occurred during the installation of the package:
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

How can I create the guidelines to be passed on to plugin users regarding the installation of the necessary requirements, the wntr.

Please write/translate your your question to be English only.

With osgeo4w you have some tiny bit of freedom I think

You could just wait for 3.12 to be available on PyPi https://github.com/USEPA/WNTR/issues/441

Yes, I noticed that there is a problem installing wntr on Python 3.12. I just wanted an alternative, a way to tell QGIS which version of Python to install.
